# List of ALL Spring Boot application properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a list of ALL properties that are available in a `application.yml` or `application.properties` file when using Spring Boot? I only seem to find the [common ones](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/295

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted but if anyone has the same problem you can simply click on the class name next to the common configuration example in the spring documentation.

Comment: Duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865832/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-names-of-all-configuration-properties-in-spring-boot/37039972#37039972

Comment: @Johan Did your comment answer your original question? If not, are you looking for a composite list of properties from _across an entire project_, or only properties _from the files you mentioned_? As Santiago Wagner [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573306/1519716): more properties may come with jar files added to your project, so there's an important distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by earlier answers you may find the **"common"** application properties [listed here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties).

But incase you need the **comprehensive** list of all properties, you may refer to `spring-configuration-metadata.json`. This has the full list of properties, along with the datatypes, description and the source file from where they are introduced.

The metadata files for spring projects are located inside jars under `META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json.`.

For example: `spring.profiles.include` may be found inside `C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.2\spring-boot-2.6.2.jar\META-INF\spring-configuration-metadata.json`

```
{
      "name": "spring.profiles.include",
      "type": "java.util.List<java.lang.String>",
      "description": "Unconditionally activate the specified comma-separated list of profiles (or list of profiles if using YAML).",
      "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.context.config.Profiles"
    }
```

[image]

```
org.springframework.boot.context.config.Profiles
```

[image]

You can find more about configuration metadata [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata.format)

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm a little late to the party, but a list can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-core

Of course, this is only a list of common properties. You must keep in mind that more properties may come with additional jar files that are added to your project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The link you provided seems to be a modern-version equivalent to the one referenced by the original asker, but you do point out that properties can come from other jar files. Since OP only asked about properties from 2 files, I took the liberty of asking for clarification.