# Is there a way to get the names of all configuration properties in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, spring-boot

I am really new to Spring. I use the external configuration feature provided by spring boot. It works well and I used it in several configuration classes, often only with default values. Now I want to get an overview over the configuration properties I used. 
That means I need to know all properties set with `@Value(...)` or or with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ...)`. Is there a way to get this information from Spring? I can do this with reflections but I think this is not the best way.

Comment: The actuator functionality in spring-boot will expose these as one of the endpoints, so you could look at the source and see how they are doing it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I used the [configprops endpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/10012cfddc5479ee9a5cbe98bfe4f76483965bd1/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint.java) to test it, but it works only for public members configured by `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ...)`.

Comment: You could try my third-party Spring actuator endpoint that exposes the properties and their Spring config metadata. Optional filtering/includes/excludes: https://github.com/ethlo/spring-actuator-addons/tree/master/spring-actuator-config

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [STS](https://spring.io/tools) then there is a special editor for the application.properties file with a auto complete feature. If you are using Eclipse, you must go to the class that you want to configure and check the @Value annotations in the code.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. I want to be able to extend the program by myselve or give it to other developers who extend it without writing every configuration entry by hand to the properties file. Thus I had hoped, that it will be possible to write the whole configuration including default values into a new properties file after the program has started. By using the STS editor I still need to writer the configration by hand knowing all configuration properties.

Comment: You can create a file called META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json and add the content like this:
{"properties": [{
  "name": "my.att",
  "type": "java.lang.String",
  "description": "A description for 'my.att'"
}]}

In you application.properties you can add:

my.att = 20

Using STS, the autocomplete will be available with the description provided in the metadata file. More information here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html

Comment: Thats a possible way for the developers of the program. But what I want is to allow useres of the program (without having special editors) to recreate a default config (e.g. in case the current config is corrupted) only by deleting the config file and restarting the program. So I need to know whether there is a class I can overwrite and get the needed information to create a default config file.